# get id a when href = link

Tags: javascript, jquery

i       [image]
id = $("a[href='"+link1+"']").parent().attr("id"); not working

Comment: would you mind sharing the markup? a fiddle would be helpfull too. :)

Comment: Couldn't you just use a selector like `$("a[href='"+link+"']")`?

Comment: `$(this).keyup` <== what exactly is the `this` supposed to be? You should be using selector here

Comment: Your latest update does not clarify anything. Please post code, not a screenshot. We need the HTML markup as well to give a better answer. Consider creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to better illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 6):

There is [selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to check attributes

```
var link = $("a[href='http://myurl.com']")

 , id = link.attr('id')
```

will return you `a` tag that has `href` attribute equals to `http://myurl.com`

In fact you can use different ways to check on attribute values:

- Attribute Contains Selector `[name*="value"]`
- Attribute Contains Word Selector `[name~="value"]`
- Attribute Contains Prefix Selector `[name|="value"]`
- Attribute Ends With Selector `[name$="value"]`
- Attribute Not Equal Selector `[name!="value"]`
- Attribute Starts With Selector `[name^="value"]`
- Has Attribute Selector `[name]`
- Multiple Attribute Selector `[name="value"][name2="value2"]`

All of selectors above are listed in [jquery api docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: but $output = '<scritp>....</script>';

Comment: this script in php code $output = ' $("a[href=link]").parent().attr("id");'; =>>>> not working

Comment: @user3562892 and it wouldn't as it is javascript.

Comment: @user3562892 i recommend you to add more details to your question and explain what you are trying to achive, and where, on server or client side.

Answer (score 1):

you can use data-* to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this,

```
var a= $("a[href='http://myurl.com']").attr("id");
```

From your code, use this too

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".img-thumbnail img").click(function()
        {       
            link = $(this).parent().attr("href");
            $("#img_popup").fadeIn(0500); 
            $("#img_popup img").attr("src",""+link);    
            return false;
        });
        $(this).keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 39) { 
                link = $("#img_popup img").attr("src");
                var your_id = $($("#gallery_content").find("a[href='"+link+"']")).attr("id");                            
            }
        });     
    });
```

**jQuery's data() method will give you access to data-* attributes, BUT, it clobbers the case of the attribute name. You can either use this:**

```
$($("a[href=link]").parent()).data("id") // note the lower case
```

Or, you can use the attr() method, which preserves your case:

```
$($("a[href=link]").parent()).attr("id")
```

Comment: $output = '<scritp>....</script>';

Comment: this var a will return you the id of that 'a'! have you got it ?

Comment: you cannot get id from $output=$("a[href=link]").parent().attr("id");use this $output=$($("a[href=link]").parent()).attr("id");